# An error during bochsdbg installation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bochs

I want to install bochs which can debug the kernel.

First, I download a package, then:

```
tar zxvf bochs-2.4.6.tar.gz<br>
cd bochs-2.4.6.<br>
./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm
```

It is all ok, but when I type a command

```
sudo make
```

an error ocurrs:

```
bx_debug/libdebug.a(parser.o): In function `bxparse':
/home/guang/Download/bochs-20120923/bx_debug/y.tab.c:2186: undefined reference to `bxlex'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bochs] error 1
```

What should I do to resolve it?

Comment: Is the function present in `bx_debug/lexer.c`? Can you check if an svn snapshot compiles or produces the same error?

Comment: I have resolved it.Offcial bochs document ask to use "./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm",but if i just do "./configure --enable-debugger --enable-disasm",and then ,make,make install.all is ok.Thank you for answer.